# Splitting string involving parenthesis, whilst retaining the parenthesis

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a column named Roles in a df, that has values like the below :

```
ABCD (Actor), XYZ (Actor, Director), PQR (Producer, Writer)
```

I want to split this string, such that i get a value containing lists of each individual

**So the output should be:**

```
[[ABCD (Actor)], [XYZ (Actor, Director)], [PQR (Producer, Writer)]]
```

I am **trying** to use the below, **however** what happens is the ) gets cut and i end up with the string without the ) in the output

```
df['Role_Split'] = df['Roles'].str.split("\), ")
```

results in

```
['ABCD (Actor, XYZ (Actor, Director, PQR (Producer, Writer)']
```

Further, my plan was to create new columns, each for Actor, Director, Producer, etc
And populate those columns if the list element contains the string "Actor" or "Director" or "Producer" etc

Can you advise if there is a easier way to do this?
So the final output

```
Some more columns   Roles       Role_Split   Actor    Other Roles
                    ABCD (Actor), XYZ (Actor, Director), PQR (Producer, Writer)        [[ABCD (Actor)], [XYZ (Actor, Director)], [PQR (Producer, Writer)]]    ABCD, XYZ      XYZ, PQR
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you can use `str.findall`

**Ex:**

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"Roles":['ABCD (Actor), XYZ (Actor, Director), PQR (Producer, Writer)']})
df['Role_Split'] = df['Roles'].str.findall(r"(\w+ \(.*?\))")
print(df['Role_Split'])  # print(df['Role_Split'][0]
```

**Output:**

```
['ABCD (Actor)', 'XYZ (Actor, Director)', 'PQR (Producer, Writer)']
```

Edit as per comment

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"Roles":['ABCD Walters Sr (Actor), XYZ PQR AB (Lead Role, Producer, Director)']})
df['Role_Split'] = df['Roles'].str.findall(r"([\w\s]+ \(.*?\))")
print(df['Role_Split'][0])
# ->['ABCD Walters Sr (Actor)', ' XYZ PQR AB (Lead Role, Producer, Director)']
```

Use `str.extractall` with named regex groups

**Ex:**

```
df2 = df['Roles'].str.extractall(r"(?P<Actor>[\w\s]+) (?P<roles>\(.*?\))")
print(df2)
```

**Output:**

```
                   Actor                            roles
  match                                                  
0 0      ABCD Walters Sr                          (Actor)
  1           XYZ PQR AB  (Lead Role, Producer, Director)
```

Comment: The names are not just ABCD, but rather ABCD Walters.... so with the above script, only Walters (Actor) was retained... and ABCD the first word got wiped out

Comment: if thats  the case then the re pattern should be `r"([\w\s]+ \(.*?\))"`

Comment: ABCD Walters Sr (Actor), XYZ PQR AB (Lead Role, Producer, Director)

Comment: How can i further just create a new column and have only the element that has string Actor in it..
So ABCD Walters Sr should be my column value

Comment: I thought i'll traverse the list to find the string, but the list cannot be traversed ?

Comment: Can you advise on this please

Comment: Updated snippet

Comment: How can i do this split in the same dataframe.. Lets say one column that containts all that are Actors, and the other taking the other roles..

Also, i would need some help on  how you did it, if you can explain it that will be great :)

Answer (score 0):

Using a regular expression with a look-behind for a bracket:

```
(?<=\)),\s+
```

It splits on the comma and any following space (requiring at least one forward space) where that comma is after a closing bracket.

```
s = 'ABCD (Actor), XYZ (Actor, Director), PQR (Producer, Writer)'
pd.Series([s]).str.split(r'(?<=\)),\s+', expand=True)
```

Yields output like so:

```
Out[5]: 
              0                      1                       2
0  ABCD (Actor)  XYZ (Actor, Director)  PQR (Producer, Writer)
```

Note that `pd.Series.str.split` [takes a regular expression](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) input directly. If you want to place it into different columns, pass `expand=True` to your `s.str.split(pattern)` call; otherwise, if desiring a lists in each series cell, don't pass that parameter.

Comment: you mean 
df['Roles'].str.split(?<=\)),\s+

Comment: No, rather, where `s` is your series, `s.str.split(r'(?<=\)),\s+', expand=True)`.

Comment: It appears the output is only the first element, i.e. ABCD (Actor)

Comment: What exactly are you executing? Even getting rid of `re` and running only with `pd.Series.str.split` you shouldn't get output like that. (See updated answer above.)

Comment: df['Role_Split'] = df['Roles'].str.split(r'(?<=\)),\s+', expand=True)
only shows the first element ABCD (Actor)

Comment: Assign back to three columns

Comment: But i may have more than 3 elements in the column..SOmetimes 5, sometimes just 1

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222175/discussion-between-asimo-and-ifly6).